# Simple question about the tautological line bundle $\mathcal O_P(1)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

I have two simple guesses/hopes about the following facts.
Let $X$ be an algebraic projective variety and $i: X \to \mathbb P(V)$. Let $L = i^*(\mathcal O_P(1))$ be the pullback of the tautologial line bundle over $\mathbb P(V)$.

1) $i^*(\mathcal O_P(N)) \simeq L^N$ for every $N \in \mathbb Z$.

2) Every $s \in H^0(X,L^N)$ extends to some $s^* \in H^0(X,\mathcal O_P(N))$, i.e. every section of $L^N$ can be seen as the restriction of a homogeneus polynomial of degree $N$ in the coordinates of $\mathbb P(V)$.

They are not true in general, but are they true in this special case?

Comment: 2) is true for all $N$, if $X$ is projectively normal ($S/I(X)$ normal, where $\mathrm{proj}(S) = \mathbb{P}(V)$, so $S$ is the coordinate-ring of $\mathbb{P}(V)$). For general $X$, it holds for $N \gg 0$, because of the cohomology of $0 \to \mathcal{I}_X(N) \to \mathcal{O}_{P}(N) \to  i_* \mathcal{O}_X(N) \to 0$.

Comment: @JürgenBöhm Thanks! If I'm not wrong partial flag varieties with canonical Plucker-Veronese-Segre embedding are projectively normal right?

Comment: I do not know it myself, but a quick look at Google gave: Allen Knutson (http://mathoverflow.net/users/391/allen-knutson), Defining Equations of a Flag Variety, URL (version: 2013-05-04): http://mathoverflow.net/q/129643
So it seems the answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: Isn't $\mathcal{O}(-1)$ the [tautological line bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautological_bundle#Facts)?  [This post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487923/is-tautological-bundle-mathcalo1-or-mathcalo-1) seems to indicate that it is $\mathcal{O}(-1)$, too.

Comment: @Quasicoherent I'm glad to totally agree with you!